# Oreo: how to find all restricted syscalls at source code?

Tags: android, system-calls, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/07/seccomp-filter-in-android-o.html

As "seccomp filter" section of this article saids,

> Android O's seccomp filter blocks certain syscalls, such as swapon/swapoff, which have been implicated in some security attacks, and the key control syscalls, which are not useful to apps. In total, the filter blocks 17 of 271 syscalls in arm64 and 70 of 364 in arm.

Now, some syscalls are blocked and throws error `signal 31 (SIGSYS), code 1 (SYS_SECCOMP), fault addr -------- Cause: seccomp prevented call to disallowed system call 55`.

But I cannot find the above list of 17 syscalls in arm64 and 70 syscalls in arm.
Which syscalls are restricted? How can I find the syscalls for cause of crash?

**Edited:**

It seems that this error message is generated in here.

https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/blob/master/debuggerd/libdebuggerd/tombstone.cpp#L96

```
  } else if (si->si_signo == SIGSYS && si->si_code == SYS_SECCOMP) {
    cause = StringPrintf("seccomp prevented call to disallowed %s system call %d", ABI_STRING,
                         si->si_syscall);
  }
```

Comment: I'm unclear what your edit is asking. The original question seems to ask "which syscalls are restricted in Android 8.0?", but the edit seems to be asking more along the lines of "where in the AOSP source code are syscalls blocked?" - is this correct?

Comment: Sorry. The question does not change at all. I thought that I could understand about the filtering deeply, reading AOSP source code.

Comment: For example, whether it is debuggable from the system call number of error message. And if their number are defined somewhere, all restricted syscalls are also in there, aren't they?

Comment: The actual filtering is part of the linux kernel, rather than an AOSP specific feature. The printed message is just Android attempting to give you useful info. The restricted syscalls are the ones listed in the appropriate source code blacklist. I've edited my answer to include some info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Which Syscalls are Restricted in Android 8.0 Oreo?

The syscall filter [source files](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_bionic/tree/master/libc/seccomp) are autogenerated, but the text files from which the filters are generated are located in [the next directory up](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_bionic/tree/master/libc). Here we find a [list of all syscalls of interest](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/SYSCALLS.TXT), as well as a couple of whitelists and blacklists. Presumably the [app blacklist](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/SECCOMP_BLACKLIST_APP.TXT) is what you are looking for; I've summarized it below.

#### Edit: Syscall Filtering Background

The filtering itself is a standard feature provided by the Linux kernel, called [seccomp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/seccomp.2.html). All AOSP does is make use of this feature to filter the system calls listed in the app blacklist linked above. A script processes that blacklist into a platform-specific autogenerated filter that is then fed to seccomp for the process from which all Android apps are launched (ie [Zygote](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/77308)). Once this filtering is active, making a matching syscall from the filtered process (ie any app) will result in a SIGSYS signal being delivered. See [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for some general information on Linux signals. The error message printed by the AOSP source that you linked is just the system trying to give you some useful information when it notices that your process was killed - notice that the method name is `dump_probable_cause`.

#### Blocked Syscalls to Modify IDs

```
+--------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|                     Function                     |        Blocked On        |
+--------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| int   setgid:setgid32(gid_t)                     | arm,x86                  |
| int   setgid:setgid(gid_t)                       | arm64,mips,mips64,x86_64 |
| int   setuid:setuid32(uid_t)                     | arm,x86                  |
| int   setuid:setuid(uid_t)                       | arm64,mips,mips64,x86_64 |
| int   setreuid:setreuid32(uid_t, uid_t)          | arm,x86                  |
| int   setreuid:setreuid(uid_t, uid_t)            | arm64,mips,mips64,x86_64 |
| int   setresuid:setresuid32(uid_t, uid_t, uid_t) | arm,x86                  |
| int   setresuid:setresuid(uid_t, uid_t, uid_t)   | arm64,mips,mips64,x86_64 |
| int   setresgid:setresgid32(gid_t, gid_t, gid_t) | arm,x86                  |
| int   setresgid:setresgid(gid_t, gid_t, gid_t)   | arm64,mips,mips64,x86_64 |
| int   setfsgid(gid_t)                            | all                      |
| int   setfsuid(uid_t)                            | all                      |
| int   setgroups:setgroups32(int, const gid_t*)   | arm,x86                  |
| int   setgroups:setgroups(int, const gid_t*)     | arm64,mips,mips64,x86_64 |
+--------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

#### Blocked Syscalls to Modify Times

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|                              Function                              | Blocked On |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| int   adjtimex(struct timex*)                                      | all        |
| int   clock_adjtime(clockid_t, struct timex*)                      | all        |
| int   clock_settime(clockid_t, const struct timespec*)             | all        |
| int   settimeofday(const struct timeval*, const struct timezone*)  | all        |
| int   acct(const char*  filepath)                                  | all        |
| int   klogctl:syslog(int, char*, int)                              | all        |
| int   capset(cap_user_header_t header, const cap_user_data_t data) | all        |
| int   chroot(const char*)                                          | all        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

#### Blocked Syscalls to Change Various Machine Configurations

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|                                    Function                                    | Blocked On |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| int   init_module(void*, unsigned long, const char*)                           | all        |
| int   delete_module(const char*, unsigned int)                                 | all        |
| int   mount(const char*, const char*, const char*, unsigned long, const void*) | all        |
| int   umount2(const char*, int)                                                | all        |
| int   swapon(const char*, int)                                                 | all        |
| int   swapoff(const char*)                                                     | all        |
| int   setdomainname(const char*, size_t)                                       | all        |
| int   sethostname(const char*, size_t)                                         | all        |
| int   __reboot:reboot(int, int, int, void*)                                    | all        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems that syscalls changing something are restricted, doesn't it? I did grep them to check my app source code for now.

Comment: Yes, attempting to use any syscall which has now been blacklisted will result in a [SIGKILL signal](http://turnoff.us/geek/dont-sigkill/).

Comment: Thank you for the response with care!